Can I simplify a half-adder when using only NAND gates?
My homework asks that I draw a half-adder and full-adder using only NAND gates

I know that when you want to add to bits, x and y, the output is a sum and a carry.
The sum is equivalent to x XOR y,
The carry is equivalent to x AND Y,

XOR is also equivalent to:
x XOR y = xy' + x'y

To express XOR explictly you first need to express each term using NAND gates.
to get xy'
NAND(y,y) = y'
NAND(x,y') = (xy')' = a
NAND(a, a) = a' = (xy')'' = xy'


to get x'y:
NAND(x,x) = x'
NAND(x', y) = (x'y)' = b
NAND(b, b) = b' = (x'y)'' = x'y

The result is xy' and x'y. You can simulate OR with NAND gates by negating each term and then passing their negations into the final NAND gate.
if c = xy'
d = x'y

NAND(c,c) = c'
NAND(d,d) = d'
NAND(c',d') = (c'*d')'
            = c'' + d''
            = c + d
            = xy' + x'y

I noticed that the final NAND gate combines
a = c' = (xy')'
b = d' = (x'y)'

Both of these terms were derived once earlier on. It seems that I negated a twice, same with b.
My question is, assuming my work above is correct, can I simplify my drawing of half-adders by using
(xy')'
(x'y)'

immediately once I find them, and passing them through one more NAND gate to arrive at XOR(x,y)?

My question is, assuming my work above is correct, can simplify my drawing
of half-adders by using

    (xy')'
    (x'y)'

immediately once I find them, and passing them through one more NAND gate to
arrive at XOR(x,y)? 

If I understood your writing (I can't say that I parsed everything perfectly, but I think you made sense as I read through), then yes:
F = x y' + x' y = ( (x y')' (x' y)' )'

I think that is what you wrote about. Do you agree?
If so, then the above suggests the use of 5 NANDs, using two NANDs as inverters:
x' = NAND( x, x )
y' = NAND( y, y )
xy' = NAND( x, y' ) = NAND( x, NAND( y, y ) )
x'y = NAND( x', y ) = NAND( NAND( x, x ), y )
F = NAND( xy', x'y ) = NAND( NAND( x, NAND( y, y ) ), NAND( NAND( x, x ), y ) )

Or something like this:

I think you may have also asked about being able to simplify, in your title.
Follow along:

The two green-circled AND gates in the upper-right corner can be replaced by the product term, \$x \cdot y\$, and applied to both of the bubbled inputs because \$x\cdot\left(\overline{x \cdot y}\right)=x\cdot\overline{x}+x\cdot\overline{y}=x\cdot\overline{y}\$, which means the top NAND is just getting the desired \$\overline{y}\$ (represented by its bubbled input.) Similarly, \$y\cdot\left(\overline{x \cdot y}\right)=y\cdot\overline{x}+y\cdot\overline{y}=y\cdot\overline{x}\$, which means the bottom NAND is just getting the desired \$\overline{x}\$ (represented by its bubbled input.) That's why those two circled AND gates can be replaced by one that carries both input terms in its product.
The above can also be seen by drilling in on these two from the earlier work:
xy' = NAND( x, NAND( y, y ) )
x'y = NAND( NAND( x, x ), y )

And swapping terms, so that:
xy' = NAND( y, NAND( x, y ) )
x'y = NAND( NAND( x, y ), x )

At this point it is clear this is the same as:
(xy)' = NAND( x, y )
xy' = NAND( (xy)', y )
x'y = NAND( (xy)', x )

And that's how one might simplify further.
I'm sure you know this only addresses the sum part of the half-adder, not the carry-out part. But it should be clear enough, at this point, that you already have the (xy)' term and all you need to do is invert it to get your carry-out term.
A full-adder adds more. But let your mind play around like this when attacking that. You should be able to get to nine NAND gates, in total, for the full-adder.
